# Handling common updates to Jenkinsfile in multiple branches

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a project with several long-living branches and multiple short-living branches. We use Jenkins with [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) plugin and have  Multibranch Pipeline job defined to build our source code. We use Jenkinsfile to describe the build, test and deployment of our project.

Our Jenkinsfile does the job perfectly, however it became a bit complex. We have a certain logic depending on the current branch, etc. E.g. build and deploy docker images only from branches matching a certain pattern.

Thus we strive to keep Jenkinsfile *the same* in each branch. However, sometimes we need to make an update to the Jenkinsfile and it requires us to update the same file in all the branches.

How to handle such "common updates" to Jenkinsfile in all the branches and still have a possibility to use the "Multibranch Pipeline" job type? Is it possible to have a single Jenkinsfile for the project and still have a possibility to use the "Multibranch Pipeline" job type?

Comment: Sounds sort of related to [JENKINS-33531](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33531)/[JENKINS-43507](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43507)/[JENKINS-34596](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34596). I can think of a few (non-exhaustive) ways you might tackle this: (1) use a Shared Library, (2) use `load`/`readTrusted` or some other script loading procedure to bring in parts of the pipeline, (3) retrieve some data externally (like through a web service) and make decisions in your pipeline based on that.

Comment: @mkobit thanks for the response.Yes, I think there are ways to workaround this. But I want to do it the right way using the Pipeline plugin. I like the automatic generation of jobs using Multibranch Pipeline job type, but at the same time I want to have a single (also checked-in somehow into source control) Jenkins file doing all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented using [Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). It is possible to have a single place containing `Jenkinsfile` logic, and still have "Multibranch Pipeline" job type.

First, create a new repository for your common `Jenkinsfile` logic with a structure:

```
(root)
+- vars
|   +- myJobPipeline.groovy
```

The content of `myJobPipeline.groovy` is your `Jenkinsfile` content with some modifications. For example it could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()


    # And here goes your original Jenkinsfile content

    node {
        stage('get the code') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage('npm install') {
            sh 'npm install'
        }
        ...
}
```

Then, in Jenkins configuration go to Configure System -> Global Pipeline Libraries and define you Shared Library repository.

Lastly, in update your project `Jenkinsfile` to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

myJobPipeline {
}
```

The actual pipeline definition will be loaded through the Shared Library.

Comment: *Note*: on windows, I had to remove the lines with '#' as they caused a jenkins parsing error.

Comment: @fduff, I think the #! (shebang sequence) is optional in this case. It only tells your editor how to treat the script.